# iOS IQKeyboardManager When keyboard dismiss Black screen at bottom

Tags: ios, iqkeyboardmanager

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtLOK.png) https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79400

Top/Bottom layout guide is deprecated since iOS 11.0 So you have provide to IQLayoutGuideConstraint with safe area. While dismissing keyboard, it leaves black screen onto that portion (Please refer to the image).

I'm tried using CocoaPods pod 'IQKeyboardManager' and pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' ~ 5.0.0.

[image]

Comment: Latest master code has a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '4.0.7'
```

I am using Swift 4 And Xcode 9.2. Its work fine.

Comment: IQKeyboardManagerSwift 5.0.0 would be used for swift 4. how did you use 4.0.7 ?